# Rotation of any object locked

Tags: edit-mode

i'm trying to rotate any object on it's center but it doesn't rotate.
I try to tilt the camera but it doesn't tilt.

They move on all the axes, they rotate around the 3d cursor but they maintain always the same position and i can't rotate them on themselves.

What's wrong?

Thanks,
Manolo

Answer (score 1):

Probably you accidently missclicked when you wanted to change the pivot center. To the Right of that Button is a Button with a sideways arrow. It locks scaling and rotation and enables you to only change the positions of your objects while scaling or rotating.

[image]

Comment: The only solution i found is importing the model in another file and place a new camera.